# Woocommerce Styling

Tags: woocommerce

i have this store http://zdk.pt/iberwear , when you click to enter the website , woocommerce categories appear on the left side, when i click for example http://zdk.pt/iberwear/categoria-produto/industrialeconstrucao/, i want to change the color of the selected category in this case "industrial/construção ( industrial / construction)" can anyone help ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what have you tried so far, so we can see you have put some research effort into your question.

Comment: I tried to change css but it doesn't work, i tried also change .widget_product_categories ul li {

.children li {
    background-color: beige;
}

and for the subcategories 

.children li ul li {
    background-color: beige;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you on category page then current category has added class `.current-cat` in navigation, use it and should work.

```
.product-categories .current-cat a {
    color: red;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked!! Thanks.  so for the subcategories 

.product-categories .children a {
    color: green;
}

?

Comment: For subcategories on current category page:

`.product-categories .current-cat .children li a { color: green; }`